# ¿Cómo selecionar de manera aleatoria la mismas lineas de dos array diferentes?

Tags: python

He hecho una algoritmo para seleccionar líneas de una tabla. Sin embargo no sé cuáles son las líneas que fueron elegidas y esto es importante. Quiero aprovechar las mismas lineas en una otra tabla. ¿Cómo hacerlo?

```
def train_test_split(ratings):
    test = np.zeros(ratings.shape)
    train = ratings.copy()

    for user in xrange(ratings.shape[0]):
        print "--- Vamos a seleccionar una nueva linea ---"
        test_ratings = np.random.choice(ratings[user, :].nonzero()[0], 
                                        size=10, 
                                        replace=True)
        train[user, test_ratings] = 0.
        test[user, test_ratings] = ratings[user, test_ratings]

    # Test and training are truly disjoint
    assert(np.all((train * test) == 0)) 
    return train, test
```

Con la matriz `ratings_full` siguiente :

```
[[ 1.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  1.]]
```

Que proviene de una DataFramce :

```
ratings_full : 
eclipse_id     10  11  12  13  14
subscriber_id                    
1               1   1   0   0   0
2               1   0   0   0   0
3               0   0   1   0   0
4               1   0   0   0   0
5               0   0   0   1   1
```

Puedo aplicarlo :

```
train, test = train_test_split(ratings2, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
print train
```

Y me da :

```
[[ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Que provienen, por supuesto, de `3`,`1`,`4`.

Quiero obtener las mismas líneas que provienen de `side_subscriber_indexed` :

```
side_subscriber_indexed :  hashtag_id     
                110  111  116  117  121
subscriber_id                         
1                0    0    0    0    0
2                0    0    0    0    0
3                0    0    0    0    0
4                0    0    0    0    0
5                0    0    0    0    0
```

¿Pero cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Marine la función  `train_test_split ` que muestras recibe un solo parámetro y retorna un array (`test`) de ceros con la mismas dimenciones que el array de entrada. En cambio, tu llamas a la función con tres parámetros:  `train_test_split(ratings2, test_size=0.33, random_state=42) `.  Generalmente lo más simple es seleccionar índices al azarcreando una máscara y obtener las filas de ambos arrays con ella. No obstante, si tu función no se limita a obtener lineas al azar sino que las filtra de alguna forma es necesario que la muestras tal y como la tienes tu. Saludos.

Comment: @Marine1, cuando dices "he hecho una algoritmo para seleccionar líneas de una tabla" y entiendo que al azar, el código que muestras no parece estar haciendo eso. Para obtener el índice de una fila al azar entiendo que simplemente puedes hacer esto: `rnd_row = np.random.choice(ratings_full.shape[0])`, y con `rnd_row` puedes obtener la línea haciendo: `ratings_full[rnd_row,:]`  y además aprovechar el dato para obtener la línea desde otro array. Pero también puede ser que no haya comprendido tu código.

Comment: @FJSevilla si, tienes razon. He utilisado (este metodo)[http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html] mientras que yo había recodificada. Pienso que `train_test_split(ratings)` filtra las lineas de alguna forma y no seleccionalas al azar como como se ha señalado @Patricio Moracho. Sin embargo no entiendo bien lo que dices cuando escribas *la muestras tal y como la tienes tu*, ¿Pienses que si agregué una segunda matriz en la función para ordenar juntos funcionaría ? Voy a intentar.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho, si, tienes razon, la la linea `test_ratings = np.random.choice(ratings[user, :].nonzero()[0],size=10, replace=True)` tal vez esta una poquito demasiado complicada frente a tuya. Voy a intentar seleccionar la misma lineas de dos matrices en esta función

Comment: Marine [`sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) hace lo que parece que quieres: obtener las misma lineas aleatorias de dos arrays. ¿Quieres crear una función que haga lo mismo? ¿Necesitas que no solo escoja lineas al azar, sino que, por ejemplo, solo escoja lineas que no tnegan todos sus elemntos iguales a 0?

Comment: @FJSevilla No, muchas gracias ! Esta funcion esta lo que busco !